# Bibliography numbering issues [edited]

Tags: bibtex, numbering, citing, bibdesk

I apologize if this question has been asked before, or if it's fairly trivial. I'm having trouble getting my citations to appear the way I want them to in my report. My citations are appearing in the following way:

[image: This is an image of how my citations are appearing.]

I would like them to simply be numbers instead (so, for example, that it might look like `[1, 2]` instead of `[Knu64, CW99]`). I am including how I have entered in one of my references into the BibDesk interface.

[image]

I apologize if my post is a bit clumsy. I'm very confused and would appreciate any help. Here is an abbreviated example of my work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\makesigpage
\maketitlepage

\include{acknowl}
\include{abstract}


\tableofcontents

\StartBody

\include{Introduction}
\include{Construction}
\include{Results}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliography{ref}


\StartAppendix
\include{AppendixA}
\include{AppendixB}


\end{document}
```

and the entries of my .bib file look like

```
@article{E,
Author = {Donald E. Knuth},
Date-Added = {2016-11-11 17:51:39 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-11-11 17:52:40 +0000},
Journal = {Journal of Algebra 2},
Month = {September},
Pages = {182-217},
Title = {Finite Semifields and Projective Planes},
Year = {1964}}

@unpublished{G,
Author = {Greg Wene},
Date-Added = {2016-11-11 17:58:19 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-11-11 17:59:12 +0000},
Title = {Notes on 32-Element Semifields}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with BibDesk but with the alpha bibliography style.

Comment: Thanks for the response Herb Schulz! I actually tried troubleshooting that before. I changed it to plain but the issue seems to exist even then. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: As commented above this should be entirely a function of `\bibliographystyle` (see e.g. http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/bibtex.html).  For numbered citations you want `unsrt` or `plain` but remember it will be necessary to run `pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex` in order to see the effect of switching `\bibliographystyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to bring this to an end ...

Please have a look to the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have TeX code and bib file together in one compilable MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{E,
  Author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  Date-Added = {2016-11-11 17:51:39 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2016-11-11 17:52:40 +0000},
  Journal = {Journal of Algebra 2},
  Month = {September},
  Pages = {182-217},
  Title = {Finite Semifields and Projective Planes},
  Year = {1964}
}
@unpublished{G,
  Author = {Greg Wene},
  Date-Added = {2016-11-11 17:58:19 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2016-11-11 17:59:12 +0000},
  Title = {Notes on 32-Element Semifields}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{E} test \cite{G} test

\bibliographystyle{alpha} % alpha plain  <================================
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The choosen bibliography style `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` gives you the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Let us now change only one line, we change style `alpha` to `plain`:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

With the new MWE you get now

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{E,
  Author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  Date-Added = {2016-11-11 17:51:39 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2016-11-11 17:52:40 +0000},
  Journal = {Journal of Algebra 2},
  Month = {September},
  Pages = {182-217},
  Title = {Finite Semifields and Projective Planes},
  Year = {1964}
}
@unpublished{G,
  Author = {Greg Wene},
  Date-Added = {2016-11-11 17:58:19 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2016-11-11 17:59:12 +0000},
  Title = {Notes on 32-Element Semifields}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{E} test \cite{G} test

\bibliographystyle{plain} % alpha plain  <==============================
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result with labels like `[1]`:

[image: resulting pdf]

So you can see that **only** the bibliography style defines the layout of the resulting bibliography ...